# In python how to do I take the first letter from a list of strings and return them as an acronym?

Tags: string, python-2.7

Here is my code and it isn't working.

```
def acronym_make(words):
    for word in words:
        return word[o]
#words is a list of strings in a list.     
#ex. ["Bob","Joe","Car']
```

and I need to return BJC

Comment: `acronym = ''.join(word[0] for word in words)`

Answer (score 1):

```
''.join([x[0] for x in words])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `o` instead on `0` (zero)

```
words = ["Bob","Joe","Car"]
for word in words:
    print word[0]
#BJC
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
def acronym_make(words):
    Acronym = ""
    for word in words:
        Acronym += word[0]
    return Acronym

T = acronym_make(["Bob","Joe","Car"])
print (T)
```